# Unit-testing - TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Tags: unit-testing, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to databases in general, so sorry if this question  is too basic.

I'm trying to test a `Playlist` model which has a relationship with a `Track` model.

```
class Track(db.Model):
    """
    Model for storing track information
    """
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    artist = db.Column(db.String(140))
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())
    track_id = db.Column(db.String(140))
    tempo = db.Column(db.Float)      
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    def __init__(self, title, artist, uri):
        self.title = title
        self.artist = artist
        self.uri = uri

    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return {
           'id' : self.id,
           'title': self.title,
           'artist': self.artist,
           'track_id': self.track_id,
            'tempo':self.tempo
       }
```

and then I have this secondary table:

```
tracks = db.Table('tracks',
    db.Column('track_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('track.id')),
    db.Column('playlist_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('playlist.id')))
```

here, the `Playlist` Model:

```
class Playlist(db.Model):
    """
    Model for storing playlist information belonging to a specific user
    """
    __tablename__ = 'playlist'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=func.now())    
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))

    tracks = db.relationship('Track', 
                            secondary=tracks,
                            backref=db.backref('playlists', 
                            lazy='dynamic'))

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

    @property
    def serialize(self):
       """Return object data in easily serializeable format"""
       return {
           'id' : self.id,
           'created' : self.created,
           'title': self.title,
           'tracks': [ item.serialize for item in self.tracks]
       }
```

and now I'm trying to test `Playlist`, like so:

**test_playlist_model.py**

```
import unittest
# third party libs
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
# application modules
from project.api.models.base import db
from project.api.models.all import Playlist, tracks
from project.tests.base import BaseTestCase
from project.tests.utils import add_playlist


class TestPlaylistModel(BaseTestCase):

    def test_add_track(self):

        track = add_track(title='Karma Police',
                          artist='Radiohead',
                          uri='spofity:test')

        self.assertEqual(track.title, 'Karma Police')
        self.assertEqual(track.artist, 'Radiohead')
        self.assertEqual(track.uri, 'spofity:test')


    def test_add_playlist(self):

        track = add_track(title='Karma Police',
                          artist='Radiohead',
                          uri='spofity:test')

        playlist = add_playlist(title='Alternative')
        self.assertEqual(playlist.title, 'Alternative')
        self.assertTrue(playlist.id)
        self.assertEqual(playlist.tracks, track.serialize())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

**utils.py**

```
from project.api.models.base import db
from project.api.models.all import Playlist

def add_playlist(title):
    playlist = Playlist(
        title=title)
    db.session.add(playlist)
    db.session.commit()
    return playlist

def add_track(title, artist, uri):
    track = Track(
                title=title,
                artist=artist,
                uri=uri
            )
    db.session.add(track)
    db.session.commit()
    return track
```

but I'm getting:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_add_playlist (test_playlist_model.TestPlaylistModel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/project/tests/test_playlist_model.py", line 34, in test_add_playlist
    self.assertEqual(playlist.tracks, track.serialize())
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

what am I missing?

Comment: At first glance, in the test it looks like you've created a new Playlist with only a title and no relation to any Tracks. So of course it will fail asserting vs actual track values (Karma Police, etc.) . Also, the add_playlist() function in utils.py already adds the playlist to the db.session and commits, so the unit test probably shouldn't duplicate these steps?

Comment: I saw that you named your secondary table "tracks". This might clash with the automatic table name given to your Track model. I recommend you rename this table "playlist_tracks" instead (<first primary>_<second primaries> is kind of the convention for secondary table names).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `Track.serialize` is actually a property, meaning that it returns a dictionary when you access it as if it were an attribute.

You should either drop the parentheses after `track.serialize` (and consider renaming the property to `track.serialized` to avoid confusion) or remove the `@property` decorator.

---

```
class Playlist(db.Model):
    ...

    def serialize(self):
        ...


class Track(db.Model):
    ...

    def serialize(self):
        ...
```

Comment: thank you, but one problem remains:     `self.assertEqual(playlist.tracks, track.serialize()) AssertionError: [] != {'id': 1, 'title': 'Karma Police', 'artis[466 chars]None}`. should I edit my question or make another one in order to address this issue?

Comment: I guess there's is still and error pertaining the secondary table not addressed in the test.

Comment: You should approach this result as a new problem, so you should at least try to solve it before posting a new question.

Comment: I think what user @peekay commented is relevant, you might be missing a `playlist.tracks.append(track)` in your test.